# Change to defaut power settings

Tags: power-management

I have Ubuntu 23.10 desktop. Created by probably 7 upgrades. I have tweaked power settings many times and now suspend only works in 10% of cases. In other cases, the screen just powers off and power led is blinking until I hard-power-off the device. Device is ThinkPad Intel L390.

It seems to me that when I run Ubuntu from iso the suspend works well. Is there any possibility to revert power ACPI settings to default values, or to same settings as are in live iso?